In Applescript, I get a compile error attempting to access property in a handler
I am new to Applescript and I don't understand the behavior I'm seeing within a handler. It seem like the handler fails to compile when attempting to access a property.
For example, take this simple script to get the name of the active tab in chrome:
on run
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate

        set theWindow to window 1
            
        -- this works
        set activeTab to get active tab of theWindow
        set theName to get title of activeTab

        -- this does not
        set handlerName to my someHandler(theWindow)
    end tell
end run

on someHandler(theWindow)
    -- compile error here: Expected end of line, etc. but found property.
    set activeTab to get active tab of theWindow
    set theName to get title of activeTab
    return theName
end someHandler

Any help on what I'm doing wrong? I've tried declaring the parameter's class (theWindow as window) but that didn't help.

Anywhere you use scripting terminology (such as active tab), it needs to be in an application tell statement.

That includes within the someHandler handler. You need to include a Chrome tell block there as well.

Based on the comments from red_menace/Mockman, the answer is that handlers have no context based on the caller. This means you have to do:
on someHandler(theWindow)
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        set activeTab to get active tab of theWindow
        set theName to get title of activeTab
    end tell
    return theName
end someHandler

So that applescript understands the context of "active tab"
